# How to escape windows paths for the file() in Terraform

Tags: windows, terraform, escaping, backslash

I get error stating file can't be found at C:\file\dir\location if I escape the backslashes and telling that 'f' is not a valid escape sequences selector.

```
setup_script = file(C:\\Users\\me\\folder\\file.sh
```

I have tried escaping (\), forward slashes (/), double-escaping (\).

Answer (score 1):

The expression shown in your question is invalid in more ways than just the filename: the filename isn't in quotes, and the closing parenthesis `)` for the `file` function call is missing.

Terraform modules should not typically have hard-coded absolute paths in them because that makes them only work on one specific computer, but if you *do* want to write an absolute path then the typical way to do so is with forward slashes:

```
  setup_script = "c:/Users/me/folder/file.sh"
```

You can also write it with escaped backslashes `\\` with equivalent meaning, but that is not so readable and so forward slashes are the usual convention.

It's more common for a module to refer to files within its own directory, by concatenating with `path.module`:

```
  setup_script = "${path.module}/file.sh"
```

If you do this then you *must* use forward slashes, because the `path.module` result will also use forward slashes and Windows requires that the entire path be consistent about whether it is using backslashes or forward slashes. Notice that the `path.module` example above is also portable: this result would also be valid on a Unix system, because Terraform will then produce a Unix-compatible path for `path.module`.